# Docker container with Centos as base image is not running

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, dockerfile

I had created the Docker container for RabbitMQ using the Following Docker File, But not able to run the Container, It's automatically stops.

**Docker File**

```
FROM centos:centos7

RUN yum -y update

RUN yum -y install wget

RUN wget https://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/erlang/erlang-18.2-1.el6.x86_64.rpm

RUN yum -y install erlang-18.2-1.el6.x86_64.rpm

RUN wget https://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-server/v3.6.9/rabbitmq-server-3.6.9-1.el7.noarch.rpm

RUN yum -y install rabbitmq-server-3.6.9-1.el7.noarch.rpm

EXPOSE 15672

EXPOSE 5672

RUN rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management

CMD /usr/sbin/rabbitmq-server -detached
```

**Docker build Command**

`docker build -t rabbit .`

**Docker run command**

`docker run -d -p 15672:15672 rabbit`

Container starts but's its exit's after a second

Thanks in advance

Comment: try to remove `-detached`

Comment: have a look at the reference Rabbitmq Dockerfile at https://github.com/docker-library/rabbitmq/blob/1509b142f0b858bb9d8521397f34229cd3027c1e/3.6/debian/Dockerfile it ends with `ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 4369 5671 5672 25672
CMD ["rabbitmq-server"]` and (this is not your problem) you should group your RUN, see the Dockerfile best practices https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/

Comment: I had removed **-detached** Its running but not able access management plugin @Gabriele

Comment: Why dont you use the official rabbitmq image? docker run -d --hostname my-rabbit --name some-rabbit -p 8080:15672 rabbitmq:3-management

Comment: I need to use those particular Version of RabbitMQ @Robert

Comment: @Vigneshwaran that version is available. Indeed, that is the latest version: https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq/. You can: docker run rabbitmq:3.6.9-management

Comment: Maybe you could don't remove `detached` and add a line `RUN tail -f /dev/null` so that the container won't exit on itself.

Comment: @bill CMD you mean

Comment: But you will override the daemon command

Comment: Now able to run using  **CMD /usr/sbin/rabbitmq-server -detached && sleep 100 && rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management && tail -f /dev/null**